# how to remove outer array in django rest json response in readonlymodelview

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I getting data in array like

```
  [
  {
    "category_id": "Glass_Door_Handle",
    "category_name": "Glass Door Handle",
    "product_name": [
      {
        "product_id": "SP-001",
        "name": "RENUALT-SOLID-MD",
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/1-1_aIzfcnG.jpg",
        "size": [
          "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sizemattcp/7/"
        ],
        "timestamp": "2016-01-14T05:33:44.107117Z",
        "updated": "2016-01-14T05:33:44.107142Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to data in

```
    {
    "category_id": "Glass_Door_Handle",
    "category_name": "Glass Door Handle",
    "product_name": [
      {
        "product_id": "SP-001",
        "name": "RENUALT-SOLID-MD",

      }
    ]
  }
```

I am using `readonlyViewModel`

Comment: Show us models and serializers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are calling your api like:

```
 /api/models/?filter=value
```

And it returns your a list of objects, which contains only one element. To get a single object, just append its primary key to the url:

```
/api/models/1234/
```

If you want to get models not by id but by some other field, use the `ViewSet.lookup_field` parameter to specify the name of that field.